# How can I see IBM Bluemix object storage credentials?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

For one process I need this credentials that be in Object Storage in IBM Bluemix, so, How can I get this credentials? Where can I see that?
Thank you very much!

```
credentials_1 = {
  'auth_url':'',
  'project':'',
  'project_id':'',
  'region':'',
  'user_id':'',
  'domain_id':'',
  'domain_name':'',
  'username':'',
  'password':"",
  'container':'',
  'filename':''
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different Object Storage services on the IBM Cloud. [Here is a comparison](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/infrastructure/object-storage-group).

Below is a project with Object Storage. The credentials can be found in the *Credentials* section and/or *Service Credentials* of the service instance.

[image: example of starter]

You can create a project with the Object Storage service using the App Service console: https://console.bluemix.net/developer/appservice/create-project?services=Object-Storage

---

You could also use the `cf` CLI and run the command `cf service-key serviceInstanceName serviceKeyName` to get the credentials. You would have to run `cf service-keys serviceInstanceName` to get a list of the service keys beforehand.